# Problems Getting External CSS files to work with ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I've created my app the normal way with cmd in ext 5 and what I had done was simply put my css files (in the index.html file) and when I would run sencha app build my styles word override the ones in ext (that is things like the body tag).

Now, I've recreated my ext project with cmd again from scratch, copied in my app.js and app folder and it works but it seems that my app flashes my body tag but then it goes away and the standard css takes over.

That is, in my in my index.html I have the lines:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/scrum-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/Content/Styles/SessionSchedule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

***Added Note:
After reading, I've copied the css from the two files into /sass/etc/all.scss and that pushed the css into the top of the generated file but it still seems to be overridden.

(also posted to sencha forums yesterday but got no response so trying here)

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do. Including my own JS or CSS files works fine for me.

Comment: I realized I had not updated the theme type when I recreated the app and that caused issues.  once I changed back to the original gray theme the css worked correctly I had written before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding them to `app.json`:

```
"css": [
    { "path": "Content/Styles/scrum-style.css" },
    { "path": "Content/Styles/SessionSchedule.css" },
    {
        // this entry uses an ant variable that is the calculated
        // value of the generated output css file for the app,
        // defined in .sencha/app/defaults.properties
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true,
        "exclude": ["fashion"]
    }
],
```

Or you could load them remotely:

```
"css": [
    { "path": "Content/Styles/scrum-style.css", "remote": true },
    { "path": "Content/Styles/SessionSchedule.css", "remote": true },
    {
        // this entry uses an ant variable that is the calculated
        // value of the generated output css file for the app,
        // defined in .sencha/app/defaults.properties
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true,
        "exclude": ["fashion"]
    }
],
```

But add them to "resources": [] as well to copy them on build.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to include external CSS files in your application.

1. You can add references in index.html file. In this case after build you need to manual copy CSS files in build application resources folder.
2. You can add reference in app.json file in css array and build app. In this case if you do change in css file , you need to build app.